# Как убрать на графике highcharts группировку времени?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, график, highcharts

Есть вот такой график:

```
 var data =[[1488443024345,1],[1488443052668,1],[1488443094365,1],[1488443110533,1],[1488446988765,1],[1488447423974,1],[1488513056234,1],[1488513836036,1],[1488513851574,1],[1488514695328,1],[1488514709362,1],[1488515284743,1],[1488515297659,1],[1488524223238,1]];
        Highcharts.stockChart('container_danger', {
          chart: {
            alignTicks: false
          },
          rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
          },
          series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Тревога',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: { 
                groupPixelWidth: 0
            }
          },
          ]
        });
```

А выглядит это следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прошу заметить что расстояние между точками одинаковое, а хочется что бы было реальное. Как это сделать?

Comment: А можно добавить пример данных?

Comment: @kb0 добавил пример

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить `xAxis: { type: 'datetime', ordinal: false }`:

```js
var data = [
  [1488443024345, 1],
  [1488443052668, 1],
  [1488443094365, 1],
  [1488443110533, 1],
  [1488446988765, 1],
  [1488447423974, 1],
  [1488513056234, 1],
  [1488513836036, 1],
  [1488513851574, 1],
  [1488514695328, 1],
  [1488514709362, 1],
  [1488515284743, 1],
  [1488515297659, 1],
  [1488524223238, 1]
];

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    alignTicks: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    ordinal: false
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Тревога',
    data: data,
    dataGrouping: {
      groupPixelWidth: 0
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.6/css/highcharts.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.6/js/highstock.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```